Netsuite SystemNotes Data Grab
I am using a developer role account with enough permissions to see all the system record notes that my admin account is able to see in Netsuite UI. (Quantity changes, dates, etc for a transaction)
However, when pulling data out using SuiteQL, I see close to nothing what what I see in the UI.
It is using the developer access token but I thought if it had permissions to see the data in the UI, it would also show in the response.
What am I missing?

Even though your developer role has visibility into the records in the UI, certain fields (like system notes) might have restrictions when accessed via SuiteQL. Some fields, especially audit-type fields (such as quantity changes and modification dates), may not be directly exposed through SuiteQL or may require additional permissions for API access.

I see, thank you!
